# Resizing parent div to contain child?

Tags: html, css

My code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/yaphurt0/8/
I tried to get rid of the rest of the webpage to show just the necessary section, but it ended up not displaying correctly, and I couldn't figure out why for the life of me. 
Regardless, I've trimmed away what I could and marked in comments in the css file the relevant code.

My problem is that I am trying to display 3 boxes at the bottom of the page next to each other. As the window shrinks I use a media query to increase the width of the boxes so there are 2 per line, and then 1 if the the window shrinks further. Of course this means the boxes take up more room vertically, meaning they spill out as the parent div doesn't scale with it.

I have tried `overflow: auto;` to `#me`, however this just added a scrollbar to the content, when instead I want the `#me` to scale accordingly to contain its children.  This is a pretty big problem which is stumping me, as you can see from the main text ("Hi I'm Danny..."), that also suffers from the same issues if the webpage is made very wide and shallow.

As much as I'm looking for a solution, I'm really hoping for an explanation so I can understand why the webpage is behaving as it is/what makes the parent scale, so in the future I don't just copy and paste and hope.

```css
#me {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: white;
}

#me .container {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#me .container .introduction {
  height: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#me .container .introduction .title,
.subInfo {
  width: 80%;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}

#me .container .introduction .title {
  font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

#me .container .introduction .subInfo {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Unica One', cursive;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

#me .container .infoBody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  min-height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#me .container .infoBody .columnInfo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 31.5%;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid #e8eaed;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .minimalHeading {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
  }
  #me .container .infoBody .columnInfo {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .minimalHeading .contactMe a {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .minimalHeading {
    font-size: 7.5vw;
  }
  #me .container .infoBody .columnInfo {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .minimalHeading .contactMe a {
    font-size: 5vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="me">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="introduction">
      <p class="title">My Skillset</p>
      <p class="subInfo">The standard Web-development stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="infoBody">
      <div class="columnInfo">Hi</div>
      <div class="columnInfo">There</div>
      <div class="columnInfo">You!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in float:left property of the `.columnInfo` element and the height: 45% of `#me` element. If you remove those, you will see that #me will contain all three `.columnInfo` elements, but they will be stacked on top of each other. You can use display:flex on the `.infobody` to make them wrap next to each other. You will have to give your `.columninfo` elements an absolute height though.

Comment: Thanks for the help, It's tricky trying to make the page responsive with absolute heights and widths, but I'll just add some break points in and that should hopefully do the trick!

Comment: yes, you can use percentages too, but in your case, the `.columnInfo` element is 100% of the `.infoBody` element, which is 100% of the `.container` element, which is 100% of the `#me` element, which is 45% of the body. That works, until you make that responsive, because in that case the contents of `.infoBody` become 200% of its height (because you stack two `.columnInfo` elements that are each 100%). In other words, if you want `#me` to scale with its content, you shouldn't give it a fixed 45% height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex, like mentioned. Or simply add a clear to infoBody, like so:

```
// html
<div class="infoBody clear">
//css
.clear::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The problem is your `.columnInfo`. Elements with the `float` property are no longer part of the normal flow of the page, so the containing div doesn't know how high they are. The clear solves this problem by adding a hidden pseudo element below those columns and forcing the containing div down.